# Sonar Test Damage to Structures Underwater, i.e. underwater freeway tunnels, etc

Tags: acoustics

Can sonar testing (active) create damage to underwater structures such as nearby tunnels and communication cables?

Comment: Hi Sharon. I suspect you would get a better response if you asked this on the  [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ... and if you think that's a better home for your question, please flag this for a moderator to migrate it instead of cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

no. the acoustic power levels used for that purpose are far too small to damage structures, but may be strong enough to damage the hearing of marine mammals in the vicinity.